# how to use angular filter based on the elements inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have array that looks like this:

```
    [
{orderDetails: {seatid:1,orderId:12}, orderLine: Array(1)},
{orderDetails: {seatid:2,orderId:13}, orderLine: Array(2)},
{orderDetails: {seatid:3,orderId:14}, orderLine: Array(1)},
{orderDetails: {seatid:4,orderId:14}, orderLine: Array(3)}
    ]
```

in my html code I have something like this:

```
<input id="seat_number" ng-model="seatNumberSearch" type="text" class="validate">

<ul class="orderList">
<li class="order" ng-repeat="order in orders | filter: {orderDetails.seat_number : seatNumberSearch}">
<p>Customer name: <span class="b">{{order.orderDetails.customer_name}}</span><br>Order ID: <span class="b">{{order.orderDetails.id}}</span><br>Seat ID: <span class="b">{{order.orderDetails.seat_number}}</span></p>
</li>
</ul>
```

every time I run this, 
it shows this error message:

```
Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 31 of the expression [orders | filter: {orderDetails.seat_number : seatNumberSearch}] starting at [.seat_number : seatNumberSearch}].
```

Note: order details has more key value pair I just do not include it in the array to make it short.

I want to filter the data based on seatID. how can I use filter in nested object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you should create `customFilter : 'orderDetails.seat_number' : seatNumberSearch`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.orders = [{ 
      orderDetails: { seatid: 1, orderId: 12, seat_number: '10' },
      orderLine: Array(1)
    }, {
      orderDetails: { seatid: 2, orderId: 13, seat_number: '21' },
      orderLine: Array(2)
    }, {
      orderDetails: { seatid: 3, orderId: 14, seat_number: '30' },
      orderLine: Array(1)
    }, {
      orderDetails: { seatid: 4, orderId: 14, seat_number: '42' },
      orderLine: Array(3)
    }
  ]
}).filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(data, nested, search) {    
    if (!search)
      return data;
    var props = nested.split('.');
    return data.filter(function(x) {            
      var temp = x;
      for(var prop of props){
         temp = temp[prop];
         if(!temp)
            return false;
      }
      return temp.indexOf(search) != -1;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input id="seat_number" ng-model="seatNumberSearch" type="text" class="validate">
  <ul class="orderList">
    <li class="order" ng-repeat="order in orders | customFilter : 'orderDetails.seat_number' : seatNumberSearch">
      <p>seatid: {{order.orderDetails.seatid}}, seat_number: {{order.orderDetails.seat_number}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: I think, I really have to create custom filter. Thank you for your help.